# Inner Product Notation Question

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, inner-products

While doing homework for a professor with notation completely different from my last semester professor's notation, I've become stuck trying to interpret what this means:

$$
v \rightarrow \langle-,v\rangle_V
$$
where $\langle,\rangle_V$ is an inner product on a finite-dimensional real vector space, $V$. The entire question is to show that the above identifies $V$ with $V^*$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can map each vector in the space $V$ to the linear functional defined by $\langle u, v \rangle_V$ where $u$ is an arbitrary element of $V$. The $-$ is just a placeholder to signify that $u$ is arbitary. The functional we identify to $v\in V$ isn't defined by $u$ if that makes more sense.

Comment: It does, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This denotes a map $T:V\to V^*$, mapping $v\in V$ to $f_v\in V^*$, where $f_v:V\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$$f_v(x)=\langle x,v\rangle_V $$
for $x\in V$.  The question is then to show that $T$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer!

Comment: @Xodus You're welcome!  Informative is what I was going for.